# JQuery: Hide Problem with MSIE, Safari, Chrome

Tags: jquery, hide

$(function() { 
       $('#IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_ddl_Abflughafen > option[value*="TR"]').attr("style", "display: none;");

does not hide options in a select. Also .hide does not work. What's wrong here? In Firefox it's ok.

Thx a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox for some reason is the only browser I've used that let's you modify `<option>` elements via CSS.

In truth, you cannot hide `<option>` elements - they must be removed from the `<select>`'s `options[]` array.

**Edit:**

Example:

```
(function () {
    var select = $('#IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_ddl_Abflughafen');
    var diff = 0;
    console.dir(select[0].options);
    select.find('option').each(function(x) {
        if ($(this).is('[value*="TR"]')) {
            select[0].options[x+diff] = null;
            diff -= 1;
        }
    });
}());​
```

You can see the example live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vTUvU/).

The idea is to pull ALL `<option>` children from the `<select>`. This is necessary for proper indexing (so we remove the right thing).

We then iterate through the `<option>`s and run your selector against them. If it matches, we remove that option based on the index passed by `each`.

The `diff` is counting the removals so we do not remove the wrong `<option>` as the `options[]` array decreases in size from previous deletions.

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: sorry. didn't notice your edit. I will try it, thx. But I want to hide the option instead of .remove. Cause I need to show it back later.

Comment: @ceyago - in that case, you're probably going to have to manage a separate array that keeps track of the hidden options so they can be added back later

Comment: In Safari it's ok with remove. Unfortunately Firefox is making trouble.

http://jsfiddle.net/Axaag/10/

Could you please help me again with the separate array issue?

Comment: I think I will try disabling the options instead of hiding.

http://jsfiddle.net/Axaag/12/

thx a lot Matt, esp. for jsFiddle. Didn't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are happy to remove the option and do not require it later then this would be simpler...

```
$('#IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_ddl_Abflughafen option[value*="TR"]').remove();
```